# How to create the border of a dynamic canvas in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, canvas

Hi I am creating a Canvas in code behind like below:

```
Canvas musicPlayerCanvas = new Canvas();
                    musicPlayerCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    musicPlayerCanvas.Height = 80;
                    musicPlayerCanvas.Width = 1018;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(musicPlayerCanvas);

musicPlayerCanvas.Children.Add(playingText);
musicPlayerCanvas.Children.Add(albumImage);
```

Now how can I add border to the canvas from the codebehind.

I tried with creating a Border and assigning a child like below:

```
Border myBorder = new Border();
                    //Border Proporties



                    Canvas.SetTop(musicPlayerCanvas, 26);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(musicPlayerCanvas, 154);
                    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(musicPlayerCanvas);
                    myBorder.Child = musicPlayerCanvas;
```

It is not working for me . Any help please.

Thanks,
Subhen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the canvas to the border, like so:

```
Canvas musicPlayerCanvas = new Canvas();
musicPlayerCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);

Border border = new Border();
border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
border.Height = 80;
border.Width = 1018;
border.Child = musicPlayerCanvas;

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(border);
```

On a side note, when using controls like text boxes and images (which is what I think you might be doing looking at your control names), you might want to use a Grid rather than a Canvas as a container control.
Cheers,
Phil